# Method to hard delete nodes in BST with lazy deletion

Tags: java, binary-search-tree, soft-delete

I have an assignment in class where we are implementing a BST with lazy deletion. When a node is removed it is just flagged as deleted and not actually removed from the tree. We have to create a method for the case when we want to actually hard delete all the nodes flagged as deleted in the tree.

Right now I am using a method, delete(), that recurses down the tree. If it finds a node flagged as deleted it calls removeHard() with all the remove mechanics in it. I have tested the delete() method and I seem to be traversing the tree correctly and catching all the marked nodes which then get passed in to my removeHard() method. And separately, when I call removeHard() publicly in my main method as a test it properly removes the nodes. In conjunction it is either not removing the nodes at all or creating duplicates.

```
protected void delete( FHlazySTNode<E> root )
{
  if ( root == null )
     return;

  if ( root.rtChild != null )
     delete(root.rtChild);
  if (root.deleted)
     removeHard(root);
  if ( root.lftChild != null )
     delete(root.lftChild);

}

   protected FHlazySTNode<E> removeHard( FHlazySTNode<E> root )
{

  if (root == null)
     return null;

  if (root.lftChild != null && root.rtChild != null)
  {
     root.data = findMin(root.rtChild).data;
     root.deleted = findMin(root.rtChild).deleted;
     root.rtChild = removeHard(root.rtChild);
  }
  else
  {
     root =
        (root.lftChild != null)? root.lftChild : root.rtChild;
  }
  return root;
}
```

Comment: "in conjunction something seems to be tripping up between these two methods" is very vogue...

Comment: Put some System.out.println statements inside both methods to try and debug whats happening.